# HTML CSS Image Gallery Not Making Squares with Auto or Stretch

Tags: html, css

I want to create a 2 column, 3 row image square image gallery.
For some reason when writing code, the height of the boxes are Not filling up grid. How do I make the height of images become square with width?
Code , CSS and HTML below. Images should be touching edge to edge and **would like to refrain from naming Pixel size if possible**. Isn't there a stretch property or something? Trying to get that to work,

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
  <img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7">
  <img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png">
  <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpg">
  <img src="https://atlantis.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/styled/1bec9ec74aac91e70b3ef91fee1fc0f9">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3DXqVk9AhGSx2PIYoUepA1UfZFnGt_kY6iJTq3hb10ZLGhFwPQg">
</div>
```

Comment: check below code and if your requirement is fullfill then vote up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill up the box height. You should use align-items "**stretch**" property to the grid container.

```
.grid-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);.
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 0;
        padding: 0px;
        align-items: stretch;
    }
```

Demo [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Mayank0619/o2hkf3gj/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
 
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
   <img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7">
   <img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png">
   <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpg">
   <img src="https://atlantis.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/styled/1bec9ec74aac91e70b3ef91fee1fc0f9">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3DXqVk9AhGSx2PIYoUepA1UfZFnGt_kY6iJTq3hb10ZLGhFwPQg">
</div>
```

Also make sure to use same size images in case you want to use `height:auto`

Comment: does not create squares please remove answer,also trying to refrain from pixel size specifications.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution and when you resize your window then images will automatically resize.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: stretch; /* Default. Items are stretched to fit the container */
}

img {
   width: 100%;
   height:auto;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
   <img src="https://www.woodlandtrust.org.uk/media/100078482/Sycamore01.jpg?cb=-11897985&amp;preset=gallery-tab-main-image">
   <img src="https://statesymbolsusa.org/sites/statesymbolsusa.org/files/styles/symbol_thumbnail__medium/public/primary-images/Applesfreshpicked.jpg?itok=YmYkBfY7">
   <img src="https://openbookphilly.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/bookstack.png">
   <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5b86fce8900cb57bbfd1e7ee/master/w_582,c_limit/Jaguar_I-PACE_S_Indus-Silver_065.jpg">
   <img src="https://atlantis.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/styled/1bec9ec74aac91e70b3ef91fee1fc0f9">
   <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR3DXqVk9AhGSx2PIYoUepA1UfZFnGt_kY6iJTq3hb10ZLGhFwPQg">
</div>
```

This is your source link  [your source code](https://jsfiddle.net/y1L2mxrk/)